# What is the coefficient of the lowest power in this expression?

Tags: polynomials

I have a function $f(x) = (a+2b)\dfrac{1}{x^4} + \left[\dfrac{a}{(x-a)}\right]^4 + \dfrac{1}{x}$.

I am required to find the coefficient of the lowest power of $x$ in $f(x)$.

Is it just $(a+2b)$? Or should I account for the  $\left[\dfrac{a}{(x-a)}\right]^4$ term as well?

I'm asking because I can write this term as:
$$
\left[\frac{a}{(x-a)}\right]^4 = \left[\frac{a}{(x-a)} + \frac{x-x}{(x-a)} \right]^4= \left[\frac{x}{(x-a)} -1\right]^4,
$$
which seems to suggest that this term "carries no power". I know this may be a very elementary question but I can't find an answer to this so any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Your rewrite has $a^4$ in the numerator while the original problem just has $a$

Comment: @RossMillikan  Thanks for pointing it out. I've fixed it